# On Debian, how do I add a Python package in dist-packages to a virtualenv?

Tags: debian, python

Given some python package in `/usr/share/pyshared/` or `/usr/lib/pythonX.Y/dist-packages/` (take `python-numpy` or `python-scipy` for example), how do I add that package to a virtualenv?

When adding the package to the virtualenv, does it require that it uses the "normal" python installation method (`setpy.py` etc.) to install, or have it's own?

Basically, I want to be able to easily add python packages, which have C extensions that are complex (`numpy`, `scipy`, `pyQt/pyside`, `pygtk` etc.), to a virtualenv.

Comment: [This thread (and the linked mailing list reply) contains some information that might be helpful (albeit in an Ubuntu context)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1215610/993018)

Comment: @sr_ That's discussing the `--system-site-packages` option, which includes all of packages in dist-packages/site-packages. I want to only include one package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figure since this question hasn't had any activity for over a year (as of March 2014), no-one has an answer so I'll write how I have sort-of solved the problem.

For packages whose source install method respects virtualenvs (numpy/scipy, pyside), use wheels to avoid having to rebuild in every venv.

For packages that don't (GTK), it depends on how they hook into python.

Answer (score 3):

As you indicated making a wheel is often best, especially if you reinstall on a regular basis.

For python's gtk bindings this did not work for me, and I needed some way to test code using `tox` (which builds the virtualenvs for you with --no-site-packages). For testing purposes it would be good enough (for me) to link in the relevant system installed versions, but not everything from `site-packages`/`dist-packages`.

For this I created an installable package ([`ruamel.venvgtk`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ruamel.venvgtk)), that sets up the proper links for Python2.7 and Python3.4 on Debian based systems (Ubuntu, Linux Mint). It does so during setup of the program, so there is no need to change your program. The `tox.ini` file's `deps` section looks like:

```
deps =
    pytest
    ruamel.venvgtk
```

and for any virtualenv created `pip` will install `ruamel.venvgtk` and create the relevant links.

Comment: That's pretty cool. Personally, I hope that [pgi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pgi/) succeeds, but I don't hold out much hope given [pygir-ctypes](https://code.google.com/p/pygir-ctypes/) didn't.

Comment: @aragilar for Python3 I link in the `gi` library. I hadn't seen pgi before. I only use pygtk for a few projects, but was irritated that I couldn't test it with `tox`, hence the creation of that package

Answer (score 1):

Yes, when your virtualenv is active you need to install your required package using distutils the "normal" Python installation method (`python setup.py install`), or with a virtualenv aware tool (e.g. `pip install package`).

The version of the package that you install will be the active package version for the virtualenv. It doesn't matter whether you create the virtualenv using `virtualenv MY_ENV` or `virtualenv --no-site-packages MY_ENV`. In the first case all of the packages installed in your system Python will be available in the virtualenv, but any package that you install in the virtualenv will mask the version in your system Python while the virtualenv is active. In the second case, you will have an isolated Python environment in the virtualenv, with only the standard library packages and anything you install there available.

Be aware that packages like Numpy and Scipy don't provide pre-built binaries on Linux, so you'll need to be comfortable building them yourself if you don't want to use the versions available via your package manager.

Comment: I know how to install python packages, and have build numpy, scipy etc. previously quite a few times. I would much rather just simply use the system versions of some python libraries. The question is how do I add only some system python libraries, not all (which I've done previously also).

Comment: Also, "normal" was meant cover use of distutils, setuptools/distribute, numpy.distutils, easy_install, packaging, bento etc., as opposed to path manipulation, messing with importlib and similar.

Comment: If you don't want to do `$ virtualenv --no-site-packages MY_ENV` `cd MY_ENV` `source bin/activate` and install the packages. The only way I can see to do what you're asking is to create the virtualenv with `--no-site-packages` and then copy the relevant package directories from your system site-packages to the site-packages in the virtualenv..